# How to connect remotely to MSSQL database from local, using windows Authentication?

Tags: sql-server

I have to connect remotely to MSSQL database from my local machine, using remote server windows Authentication.

Comment: Are you on the same network and windows domain?

Comment: What software are you trying to connect to SQL with?

Comment: Has someone created a login for you on the server?  Whoever did that should be able to provide you with the details.

Comment: I am in same network but need to log in with different domain credentials to connect SQL server.

Comment: we don't want to use any software such as SSMS,  we are aware about the SSMS approach. we are interested to do it using cmd or powershell commands.

Comment: yes we have the access to the server and database also.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify that you need to use *different* credentials.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are in a different domain, you can launch SSMS using the remote Windows commercials. Open a command prompt in the folder where ssms.exe lives, and run:

```
runas /netonly /user:remotedomain\remoteuser ssms.exe
```

You will be prompted for your password. SSMS will be using remote Windows credentials even though several UI elements will *look* like you're using the local ones.

This technique should work for launching other executables, like sqlcmd or powershell, but I haven't tested those. I know [it works for SentryOne and Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/connecting-sql-sentry-different-domain).

You can also use Credential Manager, which I wrote about (in addition to more details about `runas`) here:

- [Connect to SQL Servers in another domain using Windows Authentication](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/)

Comment: @Anton I wonder if you could try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34307483) - use powershell to call powershell.

Comment: I can confirm that the /netonly trick works for PowerGUI and PowerShell, but I only used it through the SMO objects.

Comment: Correction: `runas /netonly /user:remotedomain\remoteuser powershell.exe` worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different methods.

Assuming: you are logged into windows, on the same network, and the same domain:

You can connect using the server name or you can use the ip address of the server.

From sql server management studio: click connect > data engine. 
Enter the server name or ipaddress. Make sure windows authentication is selected and click login.

Provided that you have been granted login privileges on the sql server it should allow you to connect.

This [microsoft guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345332.aspx) has instructions including screen shots

There are some variations on the theme above such as if the data is a named instance rather than using the default name. But generally if you have been setup to use windows authentication you just need to know the server.

If you are using other products and connecting via ODBC you may need to configure a connection first.