# Log-in as service account in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The stored procedure that performs a CTE in production is being executed using a service account. However, the stored procedure returns empty and I tried checking this using SSMS but I my domain account has no execute functionality in production.

I tried logging into SQL Server Management Studio using the service account but I ran through some problems. First was resolved by following this link - [The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173785/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted)

However, once that is executed, it returns as if no user name was provided:
 [image]

Question is, can I login using a service account in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the MS SQL Server version(x,y,z)?

Comment: ,can I login using a service account in SQL Server Management Studio? Yes , you can login through Service account .

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "service account" in your first sentence, exactly. The term suggests a normal account that you use for a service. Meaning just that: a normal account. So we need more info. Is it a Managed Service Account? A Virtual Service Account? Something else?

Comment: If you are in fact allowed to execute this stored procedure, but currently do not have the permissions in SQL Server to do so, why don't you ask that the permissions be fixed? There are ways to run SSMS as a different account (including a service account, see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/), [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66014/1186), and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166638/1186)), but that's not really a permanent fix for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Question is, can I login using a service account in SQL Server
>   Management Studio?

**How To Add A Service Account To Microsoft SQL Server**

1. Open SQL Management Studio using SQL Authentication SysAdmin (SA)
   Account.
2. Open up Security then Right Click on Logins, choose “New Login”
3. On the new login screen choose “Search”
4. On the search screen ensure you are searching the Entire Directory,
   type in the user name, choose Check Names, then choose ok.
5. After you click OK, Click Server Roles and check “sysadmin”
6. Click OK and you are done
7. Test out by logging into SQL Management studio using Windows
   Authentication.

For further your ref [here](https://support.accessdata.com/hc/en-us/articles/203631845-How-to-add-a-service-account-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017)